# How to override method in Rails 4 Engine Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have included a gem (engine) into my application and called the appropriate install task... I have found that some of the functionality (that lives in the gem's lib/ folder) isn't quite how I would like it.

Is it possible to override (bits and pieces) of their method with my own? I have tried to create the same file in my application's lib/ folder (same directory structure), however, my method doesn't get called.

Edit:

I guess my question should be (and I'll edit it)... Say the Engine (Gem) provides me the following Module -- Gem::TheirModule is it possible for me to add the same Gem::TheirModule to my lib folder (include it in application.rb) and assume if I have defined a duplicate method that my method will be called and not theirs?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're `require`-ing your file with the overrides? I think that maybe it's not being included automatically

Comment: See my edited question.

Comment: Yes, in that case you're just reopening the class and overriding the method.

Comment: You could add your modifications in a file in the config/initializers directory. These files will always be loaded after bundled files and will allow you to overwrite the methods you would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails does not automatically require files in the /lib folder. You need to require them explicitly.
You can require these files in `config/application.rb`.

Check out the `module_eval` and `class_eval` methods: They let you change or add functionality of existing modules/classes (of course you can just reopen the class and puts you changes there).

Comment: @ElGuapo You should type Gem::TheirModule.module_eval and override the functionality you want. Using module_eval will ensure you the module was already defined by the engine (or else it will throw)

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated in the [documentation on engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers) reopening the class and overriding the methods will allow you to expect your implementation to take over the engine's one.

> Engine model and controller classes can be extended by open classing
>   them in the main Rails application (since model and controller classes
>   are just Ruby classes that inherit Rails specific functionality). Open
>   classing an Engine class redefines it for use in the main application.
>   This is usually implemented by using the decorator pattern.
>
> For simple class modifications, use `Class#class_eval`. For complex
>   class modifications, consider using `ActiveSupport::Concern`.